# Narrowing down results from MySQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a query. . .

```
SELECT StoreName, Price FROM Stores WHERE Price > 0 AND ItemDate > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 90 DAY)";
```

this query can return several different stores and several of the same store with different prices.

```
Store1, 90
Store2, 40
Store3, 35
Store1, 30
Store1, 110
Store2, 5
Store3, 55
Store1, 78
```

I would like to grab just the lowest price for each store.

So I would like the return to show (using the above as an example)

```
Store1, 30
Store2, 5
Store3, 35
```

Can this be done in a single query?

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP BY` to group items from the same store and `MIN(Price)` to get only the lowest price from every group.

```
SELECT StoreName, MIN(Price)
FROM Stores
WHERE Price > 0 AND ItemDate > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 90 DAY)
GROUP BY StoreName
```